# Why won't my JOptionPane show up if there's no text in my JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I'm working on a login screen for my game, and everything works fine, except for one thing. When I check to see if the text from the JTextField == "", it still launches the game and whatnot.

Here's a look at my code:

```
public void attemptLogin(String username, String passcode) {
    if (username != "" && passcode != "") {
        System.out.println(username);
        System.out.println(passcode);
    } else if (username == " " || passcode == " ") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Put in your credentials!", "Hey you!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

}

In my main class, it goes:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action) {
        if (action.getSource() == login) {
            gamelogin.attemptLogin(username.getText(), passcode.getText());
        } else if (action.getSource() == register) {
            account.registerAccount();
        }
    }
```

Now what must happen is that if the JTextField comes up blank, then show a JOptionPane and if not, login to the game (added later), but evidently, this is not happening. It just outputs white space in the console.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the equals-method for comparing strings. Neither of your comparisons will ever be true at the moment.

```
username.equals("") && passcode.equals("")
```